# CodeIgniter push a new values into an array of a configuration file

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I'am probably missing some knowledges in PHP, and seems can't get it work right.

I have a `application/config/cfg.backend.php` with this values:

```
$config['head_meta']            = array(
    'stylesheets'               => array(
        'template.css'
    ),
    'scripts'                   => array(
        'plugins/jquery-2.0.3.min.js',
        'plugins/bootstrap.min.js'
    ),
    'end_scripts'               => array(
        'plugins/jquery-ui.js',
        'plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
        'template.js'
    )
);
```

There I load all necessary scripts and css files, so whenever I will need to extend some of these arrays, I will simply use an `array_push()` function like I did in my `application/controllers/backend/Categories.php`:

```
class Categories extends Backend_Controller{

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        // Load dependencies
        $head_meta = config_item('head_meta');
        array_push($head_meta['end_scripts'], 'plugins/redactor.min.js', 'categories.js');
        array_push($head_meta['stylesheets'], 'redactor.css');
        var_dump($head_meta['end_scripts']);
    }

    // THE REST OF THE CLASS ...
}
```

So by doing a `var_dump($head_meta['end_scripts'])`, I see that the `array_push()` did his job but my scripts weren't loaded, and I don't know why, I'am stucked here.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'plugins/jquery-ui.js' (length=20)
  1 => string 'plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js' (length=32)
  2 => string 'template.js' (length=11)
  3 => string 'plugins/redactor.min.js' (length=23)
  4 => string 'categories.js' (length=13)
```

Any suggestions what I'am doing wrong ?

**==== UPDATED ====**

I have a main template file located in `applications/views/backend/templates/template.php` where at the bottom of the page I do a `foreach()` to load `end_scripts`:

```
<?php foreach($this->config->item('end_scripts', 'head_meta') as $end_scripts):?>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/<?php echo $end_scripts;?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And to load a specific view into the main `templates/template.php`, I do this:

```
    // Insert catched data into the component view of main template
    $data['component'] = $this->load->view('backend/category_list', $componentData, TRUE);

    // Load a component view into the main template
    $this->load->view('backend/templates/template', $data);
```

Comment: Are you actually printing the script tags in the view?

Comment: what you see when you see the rendered source code on browser or in firebug? are your paths correct ?

Comment: @BadWolf - I updated the question, pls refer to the updated section.

Comment: @user1191081 - The strange behavior is that a `var_dump()` is doing before the whole HTML source code (before where `<html>...` starts), but at the end of the file, there is no new values in an array I've pushed before, like it's not even populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Codeigniter Config class loads the config variables inside the class making them immutable without calling `$this->config->set_item()`. To add variables to an array in the config class from your controller, you need to modify the array, and then set the variables back to the config class before they can be accessed from elsewhere in the program.

```
class Categories extends Backend_Controller{

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

        // Load dependencies
        $head_meta = config_item('head_meta');
        array_push($head_meta['end_scripts'], 'plugins/redactor.min.js', 'categories.js');
        array_push($head_meta['stylesheets'], 'redactor.css');
        $this->config->set_item('head_meta', $head_meta);
        var_dump($this->config->get_item('head_meta'));
    }

    // THE REST OF THE CLASS ...
}
```

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you for clarify the things, I didn't know about that the class vars are locked for override except it's own functions.